# C# equivalent of Scala List's Zip with Index?

Tags: c#, scala

Using C#, how can I convert/iterate a List/Array/Dictionary to a collection which can easily output it's index?

E.g. in Scala I'd use .zipWithIndex in order to convert a list of [a,b,c] to a list of [(a, 0), (b, 1), (c, 2)]

Is there an 'easy' way of doing this with inbuilt .net methods? Via LINQ or otherwise?

Or do I have to use an external functional library, or code my own extension method?

From their docs:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#zipWithIndex:List[(A,Int)]

> Example:
>   List("a", "b", "c").zipWithIndex = List(("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 2))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) has override that have index:

```
(new List<string>{"a","b","c"}).Select((value,index) => new {value, index})
```

Depending on what output you need change `new {value, index}` to whatever type you want.

Answer (score 4):

The first answer is cleaner, but I was not even aware of the overload of `Select` to use an object's index.  I came up with the following answer using the `Enumerable.Range` and `Zip` methods.  I am projecting to a `System.ValueTuple`.

```
var myList = new List<object> { "a", "b", "c" };

Enumerable.Range(start: 0, count: myList.Count)
          .Zip(myList, (n, value) => (value, n));
```

Answer (score 2):

MoreLinq's `EquiZip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(TFirst, TSecond, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>)` could do this:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
var zipped = myList.EquipZip(Enumerable.Range(1, 3), (s, i) => (s, i));
```

Or you could do it with one of the MoreLinq ForEach methods:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
myList.ForEach((s, i) => { ... } );
```

Though I must admit an earlier answer's `Select` method is the most straightforward.